# How to sum + 1 to a Varchar value that has a numeric part in it efficiently?

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure

I have a `Varchar(9)` column which has a code to identify specific cases, it differs from the primary key ID because this one is created after some validation, also, the code is not created in order, we could have a case created yesterday at 6, another one at 8 and the one at 8 would have its code created first than the other one. So well, the issue is that each code should be the last code + 1, which is not hard, but because it includes non-numeric values, we have to retrieve the maximum value but it is not really efficient.

For example:

```
ID     Code
1      AA0008-BX
2      AA0010-BX
3      AA0011-BX
4      AA0009-BX
```

So in this case, I'd have to go through those 4 values, retrieve 'AA0011-BX' being the max value, add a 1  to the numeric part to make it 'AA0012-BX', also, I have to add the number of zero's needed to make it for numeric characters. Because it has the AA and -BX part at the end we can use max(Code) and retrieve the biggest, but this is a table with thousands of records and it is slow, I want to know what's the best option.

How would you approach this with code to make it really fast? TIA

Comment: use a sequence for each type of code

Comment: "*we have to retrieve the maximum value but it is not really efficient*" and incorrect most probably as well, unless you completely block writes to the table during that operation

Comment: Obligatory schema related comment: If this is something that could happen again, you might want to rethink the schema, and store the components of `Code` in separate columns, with `Code` as a computed column based on the values of the parts.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name we use Microsoft SQL Server, I know the trouble with always retrieving the maximum number in case two people are using it at the same time or if someone was also adding a new record, if you could help with that it would be great, we have some ways of limiting that but not in the database itself.

Comment: Is the format always 2 letters, 4 numbers, a dash and then 2 letters?

Comment: @Kevin yes it always is.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the format is always 2 letters, 4 numbers, a dash and then 2 letters, as was specified in the comments under the question, the you could simply use the [substring](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_substring.asp) function like so:

```
declare @next int
select @next = max(cast(substring(code,3,4) as int))+1 from table1
insert into table1 values ('AA'+right('0000'+cast(@next as varchar(4)),4)+'-BX')
```

Comment: @DavidBuck How's that?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server 2017 or above then `TRIM` can be used to achieve the desired result.

try the following:

```
declare @tab table (ID int, val varchar(10))

insert into @tab select 1, 'AA0008-BX'
insert into @tab select 2, 'BA0010-BX'
insert into @tab select 3, 'XA0011-BX'
insert into @tab select 4, 'AY0009-BX'

select TOP 1 REPLACE(VAL, TRY_CONVERT(INT, TRIM('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ-' FROM VAL)), TRY_CONVERT(INT, TRIM('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ-' FROM VAL))+1 )
from @tab
ORDER BY TRY_CONVERT(INT, TRIM('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ-' FROM VAL)) DESC
```